# Which aws database should I use?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-architecture

I have a legacy project that I like to migrate piece by piece. Now, the data is tightly connected.

For example:

- Flight information
- Crew info
- Passengers info
- Airports
- Flights can have many airports too

I also would like to have the database that is scaleable and flexible in changing structure. I’m using AWS.

I had a look at DynamoDB, it has the flexibility that I’m looking for but when I found it’s hard to query a particular single item in 1-to-many for example.

I also know how inflexible it is to change structure or schema in RDS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The decision is whether to use a **NoSQL** database or a **Relational Database that uses SQL**.

In situations where you will be querying information across many types of data (eg *"How many flights from LAX with more than 100 passengers departed more than 15 minutes late"*), a **relational database** makes things much easier.

They can be slower, but queries are much easier to write. (For example, the above question could be done in one query.)

A NoSQL database is excellent when you need predictable performance (reads per second), but cannot join information across tables.

Once you have picked your database type, then you can choose the **database engine**. Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) offers:

- MySQL (Open-source, low cost)
- Aurora (Cloud version of MySQL, much more performant)
- MariaDB
- Microsoft SQL Server (higher cost)
- Oracle (higher cost)

If in doubt, go with **Aurora** since it is more cloud-native and is fully compatible with MySQL. There is now a [serverless version of Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) that can automatically scale and even turn off when unused to lower costs.

As to flexibility of schemas, all SQL databases basically offer the same flexibility via `ALTER TABLE`.